# Get a list of application binary types - Intel or Universal

Tags: applications, apple-silicon, universal-binaries

I just upgraded to an M1 Mac mini and did a full migration (including applications) from a previous Intel Mac mini Time Machine backup.

Now I want to see what Apps I have on the new machine that are purely Intel Apps and hence potential candidates for seeing if they now have a Universal Binary version. (Some apps, such as Affinity Photo were already Universal before the the upgrade)

I know that I can go through each application one by one in the Finder and manually get this information, but is there an easier/automated way of doing it.  Basically I just want a list of application names and the application type (Intel or Universal).

Answer (score 3):

> Basically I just want a list of application names and the application type (Intel or Universal).

Testing as both an **Admin** and **Standard** account, under **macOS Big Sur** 11.2.3 on a **MacBook Pro** with an **Intel CPU**, and I believe it should also work on an **Apple M1**.

**Apple** menu > **About This Mac** > **System Report** > **Applications** > **Kind**

Or in **Terminal**:

```
system_profiler SPApplicationsDataType
```

---

[image]

Comment: @Darwin OS X,  Your attempted edit would not have improved my answer one bit and would have caused conflicts with my writing style. Please do not attempt to edit any more of my posts with this type of edit, as I will summarily dismiss all of your proposed edits of this type!

Answer (score 0):

This app from DigiDNA/iMazing does exactly what you want: https://github.com/DigiDNA/Silicon

Answer (score -1):

Open Activity Monitor, and sort running tasks by "Kind." This will show you which running apps are using Apple vs Intel archetecture. Processes running on the Intel archetecture could be replaced with a universal binary. Note that you must run an application to check if it is replacable this way. [image]

Comment: That only shows when they run and also does not show if they are Universal - Apple ones might be Apple only

Comment: Good point on needing to open a program to use this method, I edited the post to reflect that. However, it seems clear from the question details that he is looking to see if he can upgrade any of his applications to a M1 compatible binary. My answer does help identify a list of applications to upgrade easily.